# React star rating

Tags: reactjs, rating

I have a recipe app and i implemented a star rating, i have to save the value in local storage and display the average rating value.I updated the code after reading the answers in order to get the recipe id and the rating in the local storage and it kinda works.Using console log i was able to see that the rating and the id showing good but nothing is saving in the local storage and i don't understand why any help?

This is the code:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Searched from "../Pages/Searched";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const StarRating = () => {
  

  let params = useParams();
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("instructions");
  
  const fetchDetails = async () => {
      const data = await fetch(
      `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${params.name}/information?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
      );
      const detailData = await data.json();
      setDetails(detailData);
      console.log(detailData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchDetails();
  }, [params.name]);

    const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(0);

    useCallback(() => {
      const data = localStorage.getItem("rating");
      if (data) {
        data[details.id] = rating;
        localStorage.setItem("rating", JSON.stringify(data));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("rating", JSON.stringify({ [details.id]: rating }));
      }
    }, [rating]);
    
    
    return (
        <StarStyle>
      <div className="star-rating">
        {[...Array(5)].map((star, index) => {
          index += 1;
          return (
            <button
              type="button"
              key={index}
              className={index <= (hover || rating) ? "on" : "off"}
              onClick={() => setRating(index)}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(index)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(rating)}
            >
              <span className="star">&#9733;</span>
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      </StarStyle>
    );
  };


export default StarRating;

const StarStyle = styled.form`
button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    block-size: 150px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
  .on {
    color: #000;
  }
  .off {
    color: #ccc;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all make a component for Rating in React js
and follow this code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./StarRating.css";

const StarRating = () => {



const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="star-rating">
      {[...Array(5)].map((star, index) => {
        index += 1;
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            key={index}
            className={index <= (hover || rating) ? "on" : "off"}
            onClick={() => setRating(index)}
            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(index)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(rating)}
          >
            <span className="star fs-2">&#9733;</span>
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default StarRating;
```

and make css file and write this code

```
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.on {
  color: #ffd900;
}
.off {
  color: #ffd90073;
}
```

and use it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `useEffect` hook that watches for the change of the `rating` and set it in the `localStorage`.

For example you need to do something like the following:

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

  const StarRating = () => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(0);

  useCallback(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("rating", JSON.stringify(rating));
  }, [rating]);

  return (
    <StarStyle>
      <div className="star-rating">
        {[...Array(5)].map((star, index) => {
          index += 1;
          return (
            <button
              type="button"
              key={index}
              className={index <= (hover || rating) ? "on" : "off"}
              onClick={() => setRating(index)}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(index)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(rating)}
            >
              <span className="star">&#9733;</span>
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
  </StarStyle>
  );
};

export default StarRating;
```

This is a simple implementation that sets the value of the rating to the `localStorage` whenever the `rating` state changes.

In real life, you will need to save the product ID with the rating, so in case you have multiple products, you can display the correct rating. I would suggest you pass the `productId` to the component as a prob then set an object with all the ratings you have in the localStorage where you use the product ID as a key.

That would be something like that:

```js
  const StarRating = (productId) => {

  ...

  useCallback(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("rating");
    if (data) {
      data[productId] = rating;
      localStorage.setItem("rating", JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem("rating", JSON.stringify({ [productId]: rating }));
    }
  }, [rating]);

...
```

As you can see, we are passing the product ID as a prob to the component then in the hook we look for the previously stored data in the local storage.

If it exist, we update the data. If not we create a new object that stores the data.

Comment: Thank you for the response it is very helpfull, i was also thinking that i have to get the rating with the product id to avoid getting the same rating for every recipe, if it won't be too much can i ask for a tip on how to do that aswell?

Comment: Thank u very much! I updated the ocde with what i've done and the problem now is that i nothing is saved in the local storage and i don't understand why